# Hiding based on onclick with only one open

Tags: javascript, html-table, onclick

I have this little javascript code that I am trying to manipulate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
function HideContent(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
//--></script>
```

What I am trying to do with it is make a little question with multiple answers and show one message per click...

So I built this code:

```
<table class="hovertable">
<tr class="hovertable">
<td colspan="4" class="deep">What is the Generic Name of this Medication?</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="javascript:ReverseDisplay('question1a');">
<td class="age">A.</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
Lovastatin.</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="javascript:ReverseDisplay('question1b');">
<td class="age">B.</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
Atorvastatin.</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="javascript:ReverseDisplay('question1c');">
<td class="age">C.</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
Simvastatin.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr onclick="javascript:ReverseDisplay('question1d');">
<td class="age">D.</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
Pravastatin</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

and here is the part for showing the message.

```
<div id="question1a" style="display:none;">
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
<td class="age">Answer</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
This is Correct.</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div id="question1b" style="display:none;">
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
<td class="age">Answer</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
This is Not Correct</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div id="question1c" style="display:none;">
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
<td class="age">Answer</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
This is Not Correct</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div id="question1d" style="display:none;">
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
<td class="age">Answer</td><td colspan="3" class="notes" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffba74';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';">
This is Not Correct</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to display only one of the messages at a time.  So before you click on one of the answers, nothing is there but if you click on one, the message displays.  However, if you click on another it disappears and the message of the one you clicked appears.  I hope that isn't confusing.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do DOM manipulation with something like jQuery.

It would work like

```
$("#question1").show().siblings().hide();
```

See among others http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: As soon as I figure it out, I will accept.  lol.  I know nothing about jquery.

Comment: It's the tickbox under the up and downvote button on the left... Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, jQuery is really *the* Javascript framework that you should learn. It makes interaction with the DOM (rendered HTML elements in the browser) really easy and includes things like CSS selectors, AJAX, events and DOM manipulation. It also works in all browsers. Check it out!